# How to extract cRMSE, StD and CC from Taylor Diagram in R?

Tags: r, extract, plotrix

I have used the taylor.diagram function to illustrate several models and observation data points. The function calculates and draws cRMSE, SD and CCs for each model and observation. I am unable to extract values for cRMSE, although I tried using the following code

```
library(raster)
intFun.crsme(BNU,CRU)
```

**How can I extract the values for cRMSE, SD and CC?**

My initial code and diagram are presented below. Thanks

```
library(plotrix)
attach(data)

CSI <- ts(CSI, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
BNU <- ts(BNU, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
HG2 <- ts(HG2, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
MES <- ts(MES, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
MEC <- ts(MEC, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
ENS <- ts(ENS, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)
CRU <- ts(CRU, start = 1982, end = 2004, frequency = 1)

Taylor1 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,MES,pos.cor=FALSE, col="blue",main=NULL)
Taylor2 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,BNU,add=TRUE, col="brown")
Taylor3 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,HG2,add=TRUE, col="green")
Taylor4 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,CSI,add=TRUE, col="purple")
Taylor5 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,MEC,add=TRUE, col="gold")
Taylor6 <- taylor.diagram(CRU,ENS,add=TRUE, col="black")

detach(data)
```

[Taylor Diagram of Models and Observations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot7tN.png)

Comment: has this been solved?

Comment: No, I haven't been able to figure it out.